# CGLayerRef turns out empty only in OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cgcontext, ciimage, osx-elcapitan

I have an image editing application, that has been working through 10.10, but in 10.11 a bug came up

When I view a `CIImage` created w/ `-imageWithCGLayer`, it shows as an empty image (of the correct size) only in 10.11

```
   CGSize size =  NSSizeToCGSize(rect.size);
    size_t width = size.width;
    size_t height = size.height;
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerRow = (width * 4+ 0x0000000F) & ~0x0000000F; // 16 byte aligned is good
    size_t dataSize = bytesPerRow * height;
   void* data = calloc(1, dataSize);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = [[[_imageController document] captureColorSpace] CGColorSpace];
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host);

   CGLayerRef canvasLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(bitmapContext, scaledRect.size, NULL);

   [self drawCanvasInLayer:canvasLayer inRect:scaledRect];
   CIImage *test = [CIImage imageWithCGLayer:canvasLayer];
   NSLog(@"%@",test);
```

So when I view `CIImage *test` on 10.10, it looks precisely as I want it.   On 10.11 it is a blank image of the same size.
I tried looking at the API diffs for CGLayer & CIImage but the documentation is too dense for me.  Has anybody else stumbled across this issue?  I imagine it must be something w/ the initialization of the `CGContextRef`, because everything else in the code is size related

Comment: Ask that at Apple's developer forums, silly.

Comment: I've never done that before D:  but you're right haha just used to asking SO.  will report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular API was deprecated some time ago and completely removed in macOS 10.11. So your results are expected.

Since you already have a bitmapContext, modify your `-drawCanvasInLayer:` method to directly draw into the bitmap and then create the image using the bitmpap context thusly,

```
CGImageRef tmpCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( bitmapContext );
CIImage*   myCIImage  = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: myCIImage];
```

Remember to do `CGImageRelease( tmpCGImage )` **after** you are done with your CIImage.

I recently solved this very problem and posted a sample objective-C project to work around the loss of this API.

See http://www.blinddogsoftware.com/goodies/#DontSpillTheBits

Also, don't forget to read the header file where that API is declared. There is very often extremely useful information there (in Xcode, Command+click on the specific API)